# Call python function using Angular?

Tags: python, angular, firebase, flask, crud

I am using Angular8 + Firebase + Python (Flask) for my project. Instead of using Rest API, we are performing CRUD operation like this:

Create data in Angular -> Read and Update data in Python -> Display the updated data and Delete it in Firebase using Angular. The problem with this approach is the Python program has to check whether there is any data in Firebase everytime. Is there any way in which I can call Python function in Angular such that the Python backend updates the data only when the function is called?

Comment: Well the python code can't be executed in your web browser like the javascript can, so you would need to use a HTTP API to communicate between the client code where your JS is running and your server code where your python code is running. So perhaps have some API Controllers in your python code that can accept HTTP calls from your client code

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/products/functions looks like it is possible to execute server functions on firebase check out the docs https://firebase.google.com/products/functions

Comment: I can't be able to use server functions in firebase since the end product has to be deployed in IBM cloud.

Comment: @MaxCarroll Can you please send some reference to integrate Flask with Angular? I am struck with this.

Comment: I'm not an expert on either, but I know that Flask is server code and angular is front end code, now the only way for one to call the other is via HTTP, Since your using firebase as your backend, if you dont want to implement Rest Apis to call your python code, then you will need to get firebase to call your python code, which unless firebase will host your python code and allow you to call it, you will also have to make HTTP calls to your server hosting your python code.

Comment: Looks like you can trigger a http call from firebase like this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Answer (score 2):

You can combine Angular + Flask and use Flask as an API to perform CRUD operations with Firebase.

This is under the assumption that you know how to perform CRUD operations using python. This is under the assumption that you also know how to subscribe to results of API and use it in Angular app.

**proxy.conf.json**:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",    //set this to your flask port and address
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
    },
```

**flask.py**:

```py
@app.route('/api/getcvalue', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getC():
    # get parameters from request
    parameters = request.get_json()
    return jsonify({'C': parameters['C']})
```

Comment: By using this, can we send data both ways i.e from Angular to Flask and from Flask to Angular?

Comment: Yes.. that's the goal.. u send data from angular using get or post and receive the data as API result.

Comment: I have checked the backend code in flask localhost and the data is sent in json format in correct order but I am not so good at Frontend(esp. JS based frameworks). Can you help me with subscribing the backend API in Angular? Can you please refer any documentation/tutorial where I can look into this?

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/
This has an example. Follow from `Consuming Flask Endpoints with Angular`. Change API_URL to `api/` instead of `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: Accept the answer if it satisfied you. Thank you.